# CSS Position/Dimensions of Div with Text vs Image

Tags: html, css, display

I'm having real trouble understanding something in CSS which to my mind ought to be simple. I want to change the contents of a div of size 50x50 pixels from an image to text content using jquery. The contents swap fine, but the position of the div gets messed up and I just don't see why.

EDIT: By messed up I mean when I inspect the element, a div of the correct size is highlighted, but the text sits outside of the highlighted box and the lower elements are displaced.

`$('.cross').html('?');`

```
#island{
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url('../images/island-500x500.png')
}

#crosses{
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.crosses-row{

}

.cross{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I've made a [fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/robinandrews73/6zkLvLeg/)

Comment: How do you mean "messed up"? Can you explain a little clearer on how they should be appearing?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for reminding me to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6zkLvLeg/1/

Add the following code to ur .cross

```
.cross {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks everyone for the swift response. I think I need to reaearch line-height -- the when, how and wherefore.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to css class **cross** and remove `line-height: 0px;` from  `#crosses`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but then the text just jumps out the top of the div instead! `vertical-align: middle` no good either. Changing line-height too. Seems like really odd behaviour and incredibly frustrating!

Comment: i edited my answer. line-height: 0px should be removed from #crosses.

Comment: That's weird. I added the line-height thing because for some reason my divs were 54px instead of 50, but now, they are fine without it. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. I'm happy that it helped you.